# Issue Connecting to GCP SQL with python-mysql: don't want to use a port

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-sql

```
`db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = '12.34.567.891', 
    user = 'root', 
    passwd = '', 
    db = 'testdb', 
    port = "something-that-works")`
```

Very Simple Can I somehow make it so that it connects only to the ip '12.34.567.891'. Google is forwarding the port to 80 but you can't request port 80 or it ends up in an endless loop.

port=null or port = none will cause and error.

I have no issues connecting from my cli mysql client

Thank you,

I expected to be able to connect to the server no issues if I am able to do so from my cli - I need some way to send the connecting request to the raw IP no port. It may be possible python-mysql can't do this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

3306 is the default MySQL port and it seems that you are using MySQL, so that should work. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview

Answer (score 0):

You will have an easier time connecting with the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) a library built purely for connecting to Cloud SQL with Python.

Looks like this:

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector

# build connection
def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
    with Connector() as connector:
        conn = connector.connect(
            "project:region:instance",  # Cloud SQL instance connection name
            "pymysql",
            user="my-user",
            password="my-password",
            db="my-db-name"
        )
    return conn

# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# insert statement
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
    "INSERT INTO my_table (id, title) VALUES (:id, :title)",
)

# interact with Cloud SQL database using connection pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # insert into database
    db_conn.execute(insert_stmt, id="book1", title="Book One")

    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```